# looping through a set of iframes

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

how the program work ?
downloading multiple files with a loop, after u select the document it opens in an iframe with a download icon, after pressed the file is downloaded , the program close the the iframe and restart the loop , picking a new item and so on, the problem happens in the second loop after it opens the iframe and select it , it cant locate the download icon. 
its the same icon with the same xpath inside the same iframe how it cannot be located in the second try ?

```
def DownloadCurrentApprovals():
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ApprovalGridViewControl_ApprovalGridViewInfo_ctl00"]')
i = 0
for tr in table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
    #selecting the item to be printed 
    robo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ApprovalGridViewControl_ApprovalGridViewInfo_ctl00__{}"]'.format(i)).click()
    #press the download icon which will open the iframe
    robo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ApprovalGridViewControl_ApprovalGridViewInfo_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ApprovalRadToolBar"]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span/span/span/span').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    #get the frame
    frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_MainContent_RadWindowApprovalReport"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/iframe')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    #pressing the download icon inside the iframe
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ReportViewer_ReportToolbar_PrintGr_Print_Button"]/tbody/tr/td/input[1]')))
    #switching to close the iframe
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    robo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_MainContent_RadWindowApprovalReport"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/ul/li[5]/a').click()
    i+=1
```

error --raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

[table and rows code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtDKS.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you could have shared little more information it would have been helpful, but still I will try to deduce the issue. I feel what you want to try is to go to each row of the table select the document then switch to iframe and download it. I would suggest two options here and you can pick any of those, If its not helping please share the snapshot of the dom structure so that I could understand it better.

Option 1: I see that for iterating through each of the row of the table you are running a loop for each row in the table, and in the below statement you have used dynamic xpath
`robo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ApprovalGridViewControl_ApprovalGridViewInfo_ctl00__{}"]'.format(i)).click()`
this looks great but in the following statements you have used static XPath which will, again and again, point to the same element,
for example this statement always points to the second row of the table 
`frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_MainContent_RadWindowApprovalReport"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/iframe')`
I am not sure how the dom looks but its better if you are iterating through the rows of the table use dynamic XPath to keep pointing to the new row.

Option 2
If you are iterating to the row you can use the row object to find the child elements within that row like this 
`tr.find_element_by_id() or tr.find_element_by_tag_name()` etc(prefer not to use xpath as xpath will not look for the child element but start the search from the starting of the dom, in this method also you can use the xpath but it should be dynamic.)
Please let me know if this fix solved your issue, Please comment if you have any issue also please share the dom structure of the table in a snapshot with that I would be able to help you better.

Comment: thank you for your help , i want to say that my issues is not in the loop , the loop work and select the second item inside the table and open the iframe to download, it cant find the icon inside the iframe this line ` element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ReportViewer_ReportToolbar_PrintGr_Print_Button"]/tbody/tr/td/input[1]')))`

Comment: the loop will work fine till the below statement as you have used dynamic XPath to identify the element corresponding to the row but later the xpath that you used is static  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ApprovalGridViewControl_ApprovalGridViewInfo_ctl00__{}"]'.format(i)).click() you can use the dynamic XPath to point to the next row in the next iteration, if you could share the table structure here I  can suggest better.

Comment: i think if the iframe xpath changed and not the same i will get an error that it dosent exists but i dont get that, on the contrary the program find the iframe but it dosent find the item inside of it. sorry im bit of a noob

Comment: This is because you clicked on the document present in the new row(row 2) for the new iteration (as you used dynamic XPath and it changes in every iteration), where as the iframe it identified belongs to previous iteration which is still present in the dom but the content with that ifrme is not displayed (as here you used static XPath that still points to the same iframe that was part of the row 1 ) so when you switch to the old iframe the content is not enabled as the UI is showing the iframe present in the row 2 and hence you get a timeout exception

Comment: i think i understand now, so how can i get the dynamic xpath for the iframe.

Comment: please share the snapshot or copy paste at least one table row <tr> here so that I can help